# SharePoint 2010 CQWP crashes when filtering using "Me"

Tags: content-query-web-part, filter

I am trying to use a CQWP to display recent documents that the user viewing the page has uploaded onto any site in a site collection.

I set the List Type to `"Document Library"`
I leave document type as all

I filter to: `Created By = "[Me]"`
and `Created = +30` (within 30 days of today)

The CWQP crashes for all users that view it with the error:

> Your query returned a greater number of results than the web application's query throttling limit. Please adjust the configuration of this Web Part or increase the throttling limit.

Now if I replace the `Created By = "[Me]"` and set it to a specific user, the CQWP will work fine, but if that same user views the webpart when its set to `"Me"` it fails.

What is happening differently between those two scenarios?

Is there anyway I can pass the current user into the filter to bypass the `[Me]` filtering?

Comment: I would think that the "query throttling limit" is the primary clue here. I would suggest you googled for this exactly keyword because I am sure I saw several articles and blog posts yesterday that were talking about throttling issues in SharePoint when a query returns too many results.

Guess that could be a good start: http://www.jrjlee.com/2011/02/understanding-list-query-throttling.html

Comment: I have been looking into it,

What I am trying to find out is why the query is within the limit if I set the cqwp filter to a specific user, rather then use the "Me" filter.

Comment: There's a known issue with the "Me" filter for certain list and view types in SharePoint: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d17b7dc2-df50-4e72-ac45-efd0f356a740/me-filter-issue-in-list-view-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Not sure if it's the same issue that manifests itself in document libraries, though

Comment: Hi Dmytrol, in this case the "me" filter is an actual check box in the cqwp's settings. Regardless I found a way around this by exporting the cqwp and hard coding each library I want to aggregate data from.

Comment: Are you testing both scenario's with the same user logged in? I'm thinking of a difference in read permissions that causes a different amount of results